# flexbox image is losing its position in right side

Tags: html, css, flexbox, frontend

[image]I am trying to build simple landing looking at figma. The problem I am facing is with photo inside flexbox. In the line I have image->description->image. I made this in the single row line. Last image on the ride side should get 2/3 of the screen,I want it to stay right after paragraph and here is the result.If I make image bigger it will jump into bottom.Using flex didnt help. The issue line starts from "Div class="Main-content" in css and html.Please I need your advice.Thanks in advance

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding: 25px 15px 0px 0px;
}

.site-desc {
  width: 300px;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding: 30px 15px 0px 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.contact-info {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 25px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.contact-info img {
  padding: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
}

.introduction {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 45px;
  align-self: flex-start;
  padding: 30px 0px 0px 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

span {
  color: orangered;
}

.kitchen-types {
  padding: 30px 0px 0px 0px;
  font-size: 33px;
  align-self: flex-start;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.main-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 5rem;
  padding-left: 2.5rem;
  position: relative;
  height: 70vh;
  background: tomato;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.left-side {
  position: relative;
}

.art-board {
  position: absolute;
  right: 100px;
  bottom: 185px;
}

.main-content-text {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 15px 20px 0px 28px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 220px;
  right: 30rem;
}

.left-side-text {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.short-desc-2 {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.yellow-checked {
  position: absolute;
}

.yellow-checked-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30;
}

.yellow-checked-2,
.yellow-checked {
  right: 99%;
}

.main-content-text h4 {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  width: 52%;
}

.left-side-cover {
  flex: 2;
}

.left-side-cover img {
  height: 30vh;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Like Mebel</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="images/frame.svg" alt="frame">
    </div>
    <div class="site-desc">
      <p>Изготавливаем и устанавливаем кухни в Москве и области с 2004 года</p>
    </div>
    <div class="contact-info">
      <h2>+7 (995) 508-51-17</h2>
      <p><img src="images/online.svg">сейчас работаем</p>
    </div>
  </header>


  <main>
    <section class="container">
      <div class="introduction">

        <h2 class="text-color-type">
          Современные Комфортные Кухни <span><br/>с пожизненной гарантией</span>
        </h2>
        <h2 class="kitchen-types">Тренды дизайна кухни 2020 г.</h2>
      </div>

    </section>


    <div class="main-content">
      <div class="left-side">
        <img src="images/image163.png">
        <img class="art-board" src="images/Artboard21.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="main-content-text">
        <h4>Максимальное использование пространства и простота в уходе</h4>
        <img class="arrow" src="images/Vector.png" alt="vector">
        <div class="left-side-text">
          <img class="yellow-checked" src="images/Group 839.png" alt="group">
          <p class="short-desc">Гладкие, ровные поверхности без ручек</p>
          <img class="yellow-checked-2" src="images/Group 839.png" alt="group">
          <p class="short-desc-2"> «Умные»‎ материалы фасадов —<br/> нет отпечатков и царапин</p>

        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="left-side-cover">

        <img src="images/Group87.png">
      </div>

    </div>

  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: try removing justify-content: center; from container

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i am not allowed to comment yet, but try putting a width:auto; or whatever the value you have height set to for the img. and margin-bottom: auto; to

```
<div class="left-side-cover">
 <img src="images/Group87.png">
</div>
```